# What must be save data in the "hosts" file to block telemetry?

Tags: windows-10, telemetry

I have a computer Windows 10 Pro.

On this website: https://www.andreafortuna.org/2020/03/13/how-to-block-windows-10-telemetry-using-hosts-file/

there is info that "Windows 10 does communicate directly to IP addresses which bypass the hosts file. You would also have to block Microsoft’s IP addresses Windows 10 communicates with".

I would like to save data on my hard disk in the new **hosts** file like on this website: https://www.encrypt-the-planet.com/downloads/hosts

This **hosts** file will be on my hard disk at *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc*.

Will this data in the **hosts** file be good to block telemetry?

Is it worth having a **hosts** file by saving the data from the link above?

I will be very grateful for professional help.

Comment: It’s no longer possible to block telemetry using the _hosts_ file. Having a large _hosts_ file also slows down all name resolution, so you really shouldn’t.

Answer (score 0):

Changing domain names in the hosts file to point to `127.0.0.1` in order to block Windows analytics or telemetry doesn't work in Windows 10. It'll just be bypassed. Instead use one of [the software listed here](https://www.geckoandfly.com/25083/free-tools-disable-stop-windows-spying-tracking-you/) or download a [special Windows 10 .iso file](https://ameliorated.info/) with the spyware removed.

From what I hear, people recommend [O&O ShutUp10++](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10)

Comment: Here I found 5 ways to disable Windows 10 telemetry:
https://wethegeek.com/how-to-disable-telemetry-and-data-collection-in-windows-10/

There are 5 methods to disable Windows 10 telemetry.
I would like to do it this way:
1. use these 5 methods
2. use O&O ShutUp10++

Is it a good idea?
Are these 2 points above sufficient?

Comment: Do you trust that the Microsoft endorsed instructions or Microsoft interface instructions to be sufficient? I don't. I would use third party software. Even if you turn off all the telemetry using the instructions Microsoft gives you on their [help website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows), they still send telemetry anyway as there's some they don't allow you to turn off, even when using an unconventional interface. Even now in the `settings` program, they only allow two options, standard tracking and extended tracking with no option for none.

Comment: @krzysiekp41 - 3 of those 5 ways does not actually disable telemetry it just limits it.  It's no longer possible to choose the option that disables telemetry in modern supported versions of Windows 10.  The other two methods will be reverted automatically by Windows after a reboot. In other words the article does not have a single working method to disable telemetry on Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound is correct. In earlier versions of Windows 10 they allowed users to turn it completely off either from the `settings` program or from unconventional interfaces that were built in on Windows. Now those workarounds don't work any more. The article you linked to is outdated by over 5 years.

Comment: Summary:
1. The "hosts" file (at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) - probably doesn't help
2. These 5 ways - it doesn't help (probably)
3. Does it make sense to install and run O&O ShutUp10++ to block telemetry?

Comment: If you're looking for a clear cut and concrete answer then you should go somewhere else because the only people who can tell you with 100% absolute certainty whether any given instructions online work, are the people who've actually tried it out themselves to know from trial and error. Try a forum where its users monitor their computer with [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

It's currently not advised to use the host's file to block telemetry because Microsoft certainly knows these kinds of tricks and can change or ignore them.

You'll have to expect problems with windows updates or with other functions which require certain connections in order to function properly.

The data you'll save won't be that relevant to name if you have a decent connection to your isp.

What you can try is to use something like a firewall or [pihole](https://pi-hole.net/) to include the known telemetry IP's and domains if you really don't want Microsoft to gain any data but it'll certainly need time and a bit of knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the help.